# Weird performance drop, caused by a single for loop

Tags: glsl

I'm currently writing an OpenGL 3.1 (with GLSL version 330) application on linux, (NVIDIA 360M card, with the 313.0 nv driver) that has about 15k lines. My problem is that in one of my vertex shaders, I can experience drastical perforamce drops by making minimal changes in the code that should actually be no-op.

For example:

```c
// With this solution my program runs with 3-5 fps
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
  vout.shadowCoord[i] = uShadowCP[i] * w_pos;
}

// But with this it runs with 30+ fps
vout.shadowCoord[0] = uShadowCP[0] * w_pos;
vout.shadowCoord[1] = uShadowCP[1] * w_pos;
vout.shadowCoord[2] = uShadowCP[2] * w_pos;
vout.shadowCoord[3] = uShadowCP[3] * w_pos;

// This works with 30+ fps too
vec4 shadowCoords[4];
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
  shadowCoords[i] = uShadowCP[i] * w_pos;
}
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
  vout.shadowCoord[i] = shadowCoords[i];
}
```

Or consider this:

```c
uniform int uNumUsedShadowMaps = 4; // edit: I called this "random_uniform" in the original question

// 8 fps
for(int i = 0; i < min(uNumUsedShadowMaps, 4); ++i) {
    vout.shadowCoord[i] = vec4(1.0);
}

// 30+ fps
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
  if(i < uNumUsedShadowMaps) {
    vout.shadowCoord[i] = vec4(1.0);
  } else {
    vout.shadowCoord[i] = vec4(0.0);
  }
}
```

See the entire shader code here, where this problem appeared:
http://pastebin.com/LK5CNJPD

Like any idea would be appreciated, about what can cause these.

Comment: From my scarce GLSL experience: Can't your write `vout.shadowCoord = uShadowCP * w_pos;` to do the same?

Comment: Of course you can, but in this situation the uShadowCP array might not contain all valid values, and therefore I could save some performace, by skipping calculations whose result won't be used anyway(The "random_uniform" in the second example is to tell, how many elements are actually valid). It may look weird to do this for an array of 4 elements only, but what if the array gets bigger?

Comment: Do you change the value of `uNumUsedShadowMaps` while rendering?

Comment: No I definitely didn't change it during a rendering call. I commented out every uniform call to this variable in the c++ code, and the problem was still present. But yeah, you are right, changing the uniform while the rendering call was going, could have caused this.

Comment: I would be more suspect of the fragment shader than the vertex shader. If you do something to the texture coordinates in the vertex shader that prohibits the GPU from properly exploiting texel pre-fetching, you can fall off the performance wagon really quickly; the Vertex Shader would be to blame in this case, but the actual performance issue comes from fragment shading in such a scenario. Have you tried making your sampler operations in the fragment shaders no-ops just to be sure?

Comment: My first thing to blame for the performace loss was the fragment shader of course. I started looking for the source of the performance loss right there, but commenting out the entire sampling process didn't change anything. If I don't use the shadowCoord in the fragment shader at all, the performance still is ridicoulously low. But if I comment out the vertex shader part (the calculation of the shadowCoord), and leave the fragment shader as it was, it runs with 30+ fps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to find what was the source of the problem, and also found a solution to it.

But before jumping in right for the solution, please let me paste the most minimal shader code, which with, I could reproduce this 'bug'.

Vertex Shader:

```c
#version 330 

vec3 CountPosition(); // Irrelevant how it is implemented.

uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix, uCameraMatrix;

out VertexData {
    vec3 c_pos, w_pos;
    vec4 shadowCoord[4];
} vout;

void main() {
    vout.w_pos = CountPosition();
    vout.c_pos = (uCameraMatrix * vec4(vout.w_pos, 1.0)).xyz;
    vec4 w_pos = vec4(vout.w_pos, 1.0);

    // 20 fps
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        vout.shadowCoord[i] = uShadowCP[i] * w_pos;
    }

    // 50 fps
    vout.shadowCoord[0] = uShadowCP[0] * w_pos;
    vout.shadowCoord[1] = uShadowCP[1] * w_pos;
    vout.shadowCoord[2] = uShadowCP[2] * w_pos;
    vout.shadowCoord[3] = uShadowCP[3] * w_pos;

    gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * vec4(vout.c_pos, 1.0);
}
```

---

Fragment Shader:

```c
#version 330

in VertexData {
    vec3 c_pos, w_pos;
    vec4 shadowCoord[4];
} vin;

out vec4 frag_color;

void main() {
    frag_color = vec4(1.0);
}
```

---

And funny thing is that with only a minimal modification of the vertex shader is needed to make both solutions work with 50 fps. The main function should be modified to be like this:

```c
void main() {
    vec4 w_pos = vec4(CountPosition(), 1.0);
    vec4 c_pos = uCameraMatrix * w_pos;

    vout.w_pos = vec3(w_pos);
    vout.c_pos = vec3(c_pos);

    // 50 fps
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        vout.shadowCoord[i] = uShadowCP[i] * w_pos;
    }

    // 50 fps
    vout.shadowCoord[0] = uShadowCP[0] * w_pos;
    vout.shadowCoord[1] = uShadowCP[1] * w_pos;
    vout.shadowCoord[2] = uShadowCP[2] * w_pos;
    vout.shadowCoord[3] = uShadowCP[3] * w_pos;

    gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * c_pos;
}
```

What's the difference is that the upper code reads from the shaders out varyings, while the bottom one saves those values in temporary variables, and only writes to the out varyings.

### The conclusion:

Reading a shader's out varying is often seen to be used as an optimisation to get off with one less temporary variable, or at least I have seen it at many places on the internet. Despite of the previous fact, reading an out varying might actually be an invalid OpenGL operation, and might get the GL into an undefined state, in which random changes in the code can trigger *bad* things.

The best thing about this, is that the [GLSL 330 specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.3.30.6.pdf) doesn't say anything about reading from an out varying, that was previously written into. Probably because it's not something I should be doing.

---

P.S.

Also note that the second example in the original code might look totally different, but it works exactly same in this small code snippet, if the out varyings are read, it gets quite slow with the `i < min(uNumUsedShadowMaps, 4)` as condition in the for loop, however if the out varyings are only written, it doesn't make any change in the performace, and the `i < min(uNumUsedShadowMaps, 4)` one works with 50 fps too.